# How to match with =~ in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

There is a simple email check regexp in my Rails app with Ruby 2.2.4. 
The regexp is:

```
email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

The comparing code is:

```
email =~ email_regex
```

For `email` as `bcg@yahoo.com` (for test), the code above return `0` which is not equal. But on `http://rubular.com/`, they are equal.

However `===` returns `true`

```
email_regex === email
```

Why `=~` does not work here?

Comment: `0` means the match is found at Position 0.

Comment: `0` is truthy in ruby. `0` means it matched in pos `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ruby [`String#=~`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) docs:

> **str =~ obj → fixnum or nil**
>
> If obj is a Regexp, use it as a pattern to match against str,and returns the position the match starts, or nil if there is no match.

Since it's returning `0` it means that a match has been found and it starts at the index `0`.

Comment: The method returns the result of the comparison as `return email =~ email_regex` or `return email_regex === email`. The former return false and the later returns true. Obviously `0` is treated as `false` but not `true`. This is something odd.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that `0` can be confusing, but it's a *truthy* value in Ruby, just like `true`.

However, if you prefer a result of `true` or `false`, there's [`String#match?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-match-3F) in Ruby 2.4+:

```
email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
email = 'bcg@yahoo.com'

email.match? email_regex
#=> true
```

Comment: The method returns the result of the comparison as `return email =~ email_regex` or `return email_regex === email`. The former return `false` and the later returns `true`. Obviously 0 is treated as false but not true. This is something odd

Comment: @user938363 with the given values, `email =~ email_regex` returns `0` and `email.match? email_regex` returns `true`, as does `email_regex === email`.